# How to connect Docker web app container to Docker PostgreSQL container?

Tags: postgresql, go, docker, docker-compose

I'm practicing making a Golang web app that interacts with a PostgreSQL database, each running on their own container.

I'm running the containers with `docker-compose up`

But I seem to be failing on getting the postgres container properly set up.

For brevity, links to `Dockerfile`s and other settings files are [on this gist](https://gist.github.com/andradei/922e11f469aec277ab6e) (let me know if you want it here instead).

```
version: '2'
services:
  web_app:
    build: dockerfiles/web_app
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/gitlab.com/repo/web_app
    # links might be replaced by depends_on.
    # links:
    #   - db
    depends_on:
      - db
    # tty and stdin_open cause docker-compose to disconnect from docker-machine after 60sec.
    # A fix is on the way.
    # tty: true
    # stdin_open: true
  db:
    build: dockerfiles/db
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  data: {}
```

`docker-compose up` works fine. But when the application tries to open a database connection with:

```
var pgConf string = "user=web_app dbname=web_app sslmode=verify-full password=password"

db, err := sql.Open("postgres", pgConf)
```

I get the following error from docker compose:

```
Error creating new user:  dial tcp [::1]:5432: getsockopt: connection refused
```

What can I do to make both containers talk to each other?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The reason is that `depends_on` cannot replace `links`. The former only determines order of startup, while the latter also enables access between containers by name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the docker-compose v2, it's not needed to create links between services. Docker 1.9 and 1.10 allows you to connect to other containers on the same (custom) network through their name.

You should be able to connect using either the name of the *service* or the name of the *container* as a hostname. Given that the name of the container is generated by docker-compose, this is not really convenient to use, so for that reason, docker-compose also adds an *alias* with the service name to each container.

Take this very simple example. I've used an Nginx container for convenience, but the same should apply to your situation;

```YAML
version: '2'
services:
  web_app:
    image: nginx
  db:
    image: nginx
```

First start the project (assuming;

```
$ docker-compose --project-name=test up -d
Creating network "test_default" with the default driver
Creating test_db_1
Creating test_web_app_1
```

Then ping the "db" service from inside the `test_web_app_1` container:

```
$ docker exec -it test_web_app_1 ping -c 2 db
PING db (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.108 ms
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.243 ms
--- db ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.108/0.175/0.243/0.068 ms
```

If you inspect the `test_db_1` container, you can see that docker-compose automatically added a "db" alias for the `test_db_1` container;

```
$ docker inspect test_db_1
```

Gives: (just the `NetworkSettings.Networks`part)

```
"Networks": {
    "test_default": {
        "IPAMConfig": null,
        "Links": null,
        "Aliases": [
            "db",
            "002b1875e61f"
        ],
        "NetworkID": "0f9e2cddeca79e5a46c08294ed61dee273828607f99014f6410bda887626be70",
        "EndpointID": "a941ab95586a8fdafc5075f9c5c44d745f974e5790ef6048b9e90115a22fb31f",
        "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
        "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing insights. From your answer, I changes my connection code on `user.go` line 20 to be: `var pgConf string = "user=web_app dbname=web_app sslmode=verify-full password=password host=172.18.0.2" and I got a successful connection. So in the end, `docker-compose.yaml` was good. All I needed was the additional information you gave me about the internal IP that connected the containers.

Comment: You should be able to change that to `host=db`, that's the idea of the embedded DNS in Docker, and a better approach, because the IP address can change