# Docker example for frontend and backend application

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, devops, docker-container

I am learning how to use Docker, and I am in a process of setting up a simple app with Frontend and Backend using Centos+PHP+MySQL.

I have my machine:
"example"

In machine "example" i have configured 2 docker containers:

```
frontend:
  build: ./frontend
  volumes:
    - ./frontend:/var/www/html
    - ./infrastructure/logs/frontend/httpd:/var/logs/httpd
  ports:
    - "80"
  links:
    - api
api:
  build: ./api
  volumes:
    - ./api:/var/www/html
    - ./infrastructure/logs/api/httpd:/var/logs/httpd
  ports:
    - "80"
  links:
    - mysql:container_mysql
```

The issue I am facing is when I access the docker container, I need to specify a port number for either FRONTEND (32771) or BACKEND (32772).

Is this normal or is there a way to create hostnames for the API and Frontend of the application?

How does this work on deployment to AWS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running docker 1.9 or 1.10, and use the 2.0 format for your `docker-compose.yml`, you can directly access other services through either their "service" name, or "container" name. See my answer on this question, which has a basic example to illustrate this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/36245209/1811501

Because the connection between services goes through the private container-container network, you don't need to use the randomly assigned ports, so if a service publishes/exposes port 80, you can simply connect through port 80